# arg api in drupal gets incorrect values when you are NOT logged in

Tags: drupal, caching, static, arguments, browser-cache

i have a module and i am using **node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));**
now the problem is that arg API keeps getting incorrect values when i am not logged in.
how can i force this function to not use DB cache or static value?
**Example**
the link is _http://mydomain.com/node/344983
*now:*
    $node=node_load(array('nid'=>arg(1)),null,true);
    echo $node->nid . " ,, " arg(1);
**output:**
435632 ,, 435632
which is a randomly node id (available in the database)
and everytime i ctrl+F5 my browser, i get new nid!!
**Note:** if i am logged in, it gives the result correctly, but this problem happens only when i am browsing the website as an anonymous user

i really appreciate any idea!!
Thanks